# Why won't jQuery print the whole parsed PHP array?

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am trying to store my product table in an array and use JSON to pass it to jQuery and then use jQuery and HTML show it to the user.

The php code for filling the array

```
 $sql= "SELECT * FROM XXXXXXXXX";
 $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

 while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $array[] = $item;
 }

  echo json_encode($array);
```

The jQuery code to read the array

```
jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
var output = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);

for(var index=0;index<output.length; index++){

  var itmnam = output[index][1];
  var itmpic = output[index][2];
  var itmpr = output[index][3];
  var itmdisc = output[index][4];
  var itmdesc = output[index][5];
  var itmshp = output[index][6];
  var itmav = output[index][7]; 

  var htmlstring ="-"+itmnam+"-"+itmpic+"-";
  $('#shpop').html(htmlstring);
  }
  $("#shpcart").fadeIn();
  });
```

The problem is that the browser prints only the last row of the array

What is the problem here? How may I show all the rows?

Comment: you are overwriting the values in each iteration.

Comment: You should look into either [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

Comment: .... and `jQuery.each()` probably....

Comment: I hate to ask a dumb question, but is there a reason you're pulling out all of the values in your output array but only using three? You only appear to be using `itmnam` and `itmpic`. There's no reason to parse out all the other data. You'll lose it once you exit the scope of the for loop anyway...

Comment: yes, the table is a temp table for a shopping cart to temp... save all the selected items

Comment: @RhymeFree That doesn't make much since. You are saving all the items. However, when you exit the loop and/or re-iterate through the loop, you lose them all. They fall out of scope and will be swooped up by the GC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are setting the html inside the loop:

`$('#shpop').html(htmlstring);`

because of that, the html is only set with the value of the last row

but you want to append it (i guess):

```
var htmlstring = "";

for(var index=0;index<output.length; index++){

  var itmnam = output[index][1];
  ...
  var itmav = output[index][7]; 

  htmlstring +="-"+itmnam+"-"+itmpic+"-";

}
$('#shpop').html(htmlstring);
$("#shpcart").fadeIn();
```

Comment: then check the following: is they json output correct? is the `output.length` correct?  if both are in fact correct, i assure you that my code works, maybe you had `htmlstring =` instead of `htmlstring +=` in your code

Comment: htmlstring +=  works, could you explain to me what is the difference between htmlstring += and htmlstring = ?  I'll be appreciated :)

Comment: thanks man :-)  this issue is solved but I have got a new one with indexed array parsed

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method you could try:

```
// Parse out your data
var output = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);

// Save a reference to your cart
var $shop = $('#shpop');

// Iterate your data and pull out the values you need.
$.each(output, function (idx, elem) {
    var htmlstring ="-"+itmnam+"-"+itmpic+"-";
    $shop.append("-" + elem[1] + "-" + elem[2] + "-");
});

// Fade In animation
$("#shpcart").fadeIn();
```

This is a little bit leaner. Hope this helps.

Comment: this issue been solved thanks, but I have got another new issue with ajax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120079/jquery-parsejson-doesnt-popup-the-popup-window  here is the question :( please help me out here