# ajax is not able to retrieve the parsed array by the PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysqli

I have a table sets in a popup window to show orders placed by a specific userID

```
<div id="shpcart">
<div id="shpop">
<table>
<thead>
   <tr><th></th><th>Item name</th><th colspan="2">Price</th><th>shipping</th></tr><th>Quantity</th>
</thead>
<tbody id= "cartbody">

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the ajax to send the userID to the server

```
$(function(){            

    $(".prod_buy").click(function(){

    var htmlId = $(this).attr('id');
    var idarray = htmlId.split('-');
    var itemId = idarray[1];
    $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "tempselector.php",
 data: {'proId': itemId  }
 }).done(function( msg ) {
 jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
 var output = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
 var htmlstring;
 alert ("im running");
 for(var index=0;index<output.length; index++){
  var itmnam = output[index][1];
  var itmpic = output[index][2];
  var itmpr = output[index][3];
  var itmdisc = output[index][4];
  var itmdesc = output[index][5];
  var itmshp = output[index][6];
  var itmav = output[index][7];

  htmlstring +="<tr><th><img src = '../cartimg/'"+itmpic+"></th><td>"+itmnam+"</td><td>"+itmdisc+"</td><td>"+itmshp+"</td><td>QTY</td></tr>";


  }
  $('#cartbody').html(htmlstring);

  $("#shpcart").fadeIn();
  });


  });
```

and here is the PHP to fetch the order of the passed user id

```
   <?php 
   session_start();
   include('includes/config.php');
   $uId = $_SESSION["uId"];
   $prID = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["proId"]);
    //$pQty = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["prQTY"]);
   $pQty = 2;
   //$prID = 4;
   $sqlget= "SELECT * FROM vasplus_programming_blog_pagination WHERE id='".$prID."'";  // to find the selected item
   $resultget = mysqli_query($link, $sqlget);
   $itemget = mysqli_fetch_array($resultget);

    $itemId = $itemget[0];  // store the selected id in var
    $itemNm = $itemget[1]; 
    $ITimage = $itemget[2];
    $ITprice = $itemget[3]; 
    //$ITdiscount   =$itemget[4];
    $ITdescription  =$itemget[5];
    $ITshipping =$itemget[6];
//  $ITavailable = $itemget[7];
    $ITcontrycod =$itemget[8];
    $itemCol = $itemget[9]; // store the selected color in var
    $itemSiz = $itemget[10]; // store the selected size in var
    $ITqty =  $itemget[11];
// we need to search the temp table to see if the selected item is there 
 $sqlsrch= "SELECT * FROM  XXXXX WHERE product_id ='".$prID."' AND size = '".$itemSiz."' AND color = '".$itemCol."' AND user_id = '".$uId."' ";  // if the item is in the temp table or not
 $resultsrch = mysqli_query($link, $sqlsrch);
 $itemsrch = mysqli_fetch_array($resultsrch);
 echo $itemsrch;
 if (isset($itemsrch)){
    $adqty = $itemsrch[8];
    $adqty ++;
    $sqlupdate=" UPDATE XXXXXX SET qty='".$adqty."' WHERE product_id ='".$prID."' AND size = '".$itemSiz."' AND color = '".$itemCol."' AND user_id = '".$uId."'  "; // update the qty of theexisting items in temp table
    $resultupdate = mysqli_query($link, $sqlupdate);

     }else {
        echo " user id searching ";
 $sqlisUsr= "SELECT * FROM  XXXXXX WHERE user_id = '".$uId."' ";  // check if the user has any item in the temp table
 $resultisUsr = mysqli_query($link, $sqlisUsr);
 $isUsr = mysqli_fetch_array($resultisUsr);
        if (isset($isUsr)){  // if user has items in the cart

           $getOrdId = $isUsr[2]; // get the order ID 

           $sqladdN=" INSERT INTO  XXXXXXx (order_id, user_id, photo, express, qty, unit_price, country, color, size,  product_id) VALUES ('$getOrdId', '$uId' , '$ITimage' , '$ITshipping' , '$pQty', '$ITprice' , '$ITcontrycod' , '$itemCol' , '$itemSiz' , '$prID' )  "; // insert the item with the existing order ID
          $resultaddN = mysqli_query($link, $sqladdN);                      }else{  // user has no record in temp order
          echo " else is running " ;
            $ReNth = 0; 
            $oId = 1;
            while ($ReNth != 1){ 
               $sqlNewOiD= "SELECT * FROM  XXXXXX WHERE order_id = '".$oId."'";  // generate a new order ID
               $resultOsrch = mysqli_query($link, $sqlNewOiD);
               $oIdsrch = mysqli_fetch_array($resultOsrch);
               if (isset($oIdsrch)){
                   echo $oId++;

                              echo " order Id generated " .$oId;

               }else{ // insert the new item with the new order id in the temp table
                echo $oId."oId<br />" ;
                echo $uId."uId<br />" ;
                echo $ITimage."<br />" ;
                echo $ITshipping."<br />" ;
                echo $pQty."<br />" ;
                echo $ITprice."<br />" ;
                echo $ITcontrycod."<br />" ;
                echo $itemCol."<br />" ;
                echo $itemSiz."<br />" ;
                echo $prID."<br />" ;

                  $sqladdNOID =  " INSERT INTO  XXXXXx (order_id, user_id, photo, express, qty, unit_price, country, color, size,  product_id) VALUES ('$oId', '$uId' , '$ITimage' , '$ITshipping' , '$pQty', '$ITprice' , '$ITcontrycod' , '$itemCol' , '$itemSiz' , '$prID' ) ";
                 $resultaddNOID = mysqli_query($link, $sqladdNOID);
                 $ReNth = 1; // quit the searching for unique order id loop

                   }//end if
        }//end while


            }// end if 


         }// end if





    // pars json code for the cart

   $sql= "SELECT * FROM XXXXX  WHERE user_id = '".$uId."'" ;
   $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

 while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $array[] = $item;
 }

 echo json_encode($array);
```

?>

The problem is that the ajax is not able to retrieve the parsed array by the PHP. I see that the $uId being passed to the PHP and the PHP code works fine and $array has been fetched, but in return the ajax isn't able to read the $array .

please help me here

Comment: I can't help you out with your problem, however I did find your question's title, misleading. Are you having problems with data, or a popup window not working?

Comment: I have modified the title, It should be clear enough now :)

Comment: I'm sure you'll get a better response that way.

Comment: I may not know much about AJAX and JSON, some yes, however I know this much: The `$uId`, I don't see it anywhere else (just once), how is it being referenced? Also `$link`, only shows up once. Are they set inside your `tempselector.php` file?

Comment: yes the are here:  session_start();
include('includes/config.php');
$uId = $_SESSION["uId"];   im able to   echo json_encode($array); it's been field successfully

Comment: Oh, I see, and you're using `sessions`. Ok, well I might be able to help, however if I can't, might I suggest you post your entire code? That really will avoid confusion for others as well. Now, regarding sessions. Is `session_start();` inside **every** touched file? This could be a very important factor.

Comment: here is the whole code

Comment: the site says
Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

Comment: I may have found your **or** a problem. This line `'".$prID."'"`. I think you have a `"` too much in it. See what it does if you remove it and make it as `'".$prID."'`.

Comment: Not just yet, let's go a few more entries. I have to go to bed very very soon. See what my above comment does for it.

Comment: Wait, scratch my comment about `'".$prID."'"` that's not it.

Comment: rest of the code works perfectly, the only problem is the ajax done function, the php is working fine

Comment: Ok. So, adding `dataType:"json",` didn't work? Or one such as `html, json, jsonp, script,` or `text.`

Comment: One last thing (I have to go to sleep, sorry). The last thing that comes to mind is that **maybe** `id` is a **reserved word** with Ajax and/or MySQL. I.e. `.attr('id');`. I'd look into that. Maybe renaming it to something else, that's the best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

about the ajax method, you can try this code:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'tempselector.php',
  dataType:"json",
  type:"GET",
  data: {'proId': itemId  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('body').append(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
  },
  success:function(output){
        var htmlstring;
        for(var index=0;index<output.length; index++){
            var itmnam = output[index][1];
            var itmpic = output[index][2];
            var itmpr = output[index][3];
            var itmdisc = output[index][4];
            var itmdesc = output[index][5];
            var itmshp = output[index][6];
            var itmav = output[index][7];
            htmlstring +="<tr><th><img src = '../cartimg/'"+itmpic+"></th><td>"+itmnam+"</td><td>"+itmdisc+"</td><td>"+itmshp+"</td><td>QTY</td></tr>";
        }
        $('#cartbody').html(htmlstring);
        $("#shpcart").fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if unnecesary output is present then json can not be parsed, that's the issue. problem has been solved